# A question about glide reflection

Tags: abstract-algebra

Artin's "Algebra", on pg.157, mentions that "glide reflection" is a part of the list of rigid motions in a **plane**.

The other rigid motions on the list are rotation, translation and reflection.

Why does glide reflection have to be added separately? Why can it not be considered a composition of reflection and translation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've never understood its use either.... Maybe it is a traditional thing to include since it appears in art?